# SEO duplicate page for www and non www on static site - Nextjs13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, next.js13

Here is my next.config file.

```
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
  output: "export",
  images: { unoptimized: true },
  trailingSlash: true,
};
```

I am getting points taken off my SEO score because it is flagging the www on my links as a different file and saying I have duplicate content.

Because of this I made this redirect, which didnt change anything with my SEO score.

```
export function Redirect() {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
            isHttp()
        }
        if (!(window.location.href.indexOf("www") > -1)) {
            debugger
            window.location.href = window.location.href.replace("//", "//www.")
        }
    }
}
```

My site is static and needs to run client side or I would add the redirect in my nextConfig file. Any tips?

Comment: Where are you getting your "SEO score" from? Doing the redirect is the right thing. It would be faster for the user if you did it at the server level. Maybe that is, I'm not familiar with Nextjs.